# Bulk Resolution of IP Address - Script?

Tags: ip, whois

I have a list of IP addresses within a comma delimited CSV file.   They are all located within column A.  (ip.csv)

I would like to use WHOIS, or if there is a better way please advise to check each of these IP addresses and then output the details to a new csv file (resolved.csv).

This will need a column per descriptor in the WHOIS record, such as inetnum, netname, descr, country...

Ultimately I am looking to parse the results to some form of useful data.

Having installed WHOIS the

```
 `whois 86.63.229.33`
```

works great but this is complicated for new user.
Merci

Comment: From the top of my head:  `while IFS=, read -r ip _; do whois "$ip"; done < your_csv_file | awk '/inetnum|country|netname|descr/{print}'`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little snippet that matches a few lines generated by whois. Adjust it to your needs

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob  # needed to use  @(inetnum|country....)
while read -r line
 do 
   if [[ $line == @(inetnum|country|desc)* ]]; then
    echo "$line"
   fi
 done < <(awk -F, '{system("whois " $1)}' your_csv_file )
```

Comment: Thank you.   I possibly did not explain myself so well.   What you have provided is great but I was hoping to append the results of IP Address located in Column A to the following columns.     For instance Column A will always have the IP Address, Column B 'inetnum', Column C 'Country' Column D 'descr' etc  - Thank you again. Sandy